# Showing domain name available for purchase when it is already owned?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have already visited these [question about domain value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61448/what-determines-domain-value) and [ownership of the domain.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54147/when-i-purchase-a-premium-domain-name-through-a-registrar-ie-godaddy-do-i-ow) As these question weren't able to sort the answer i was looking for, so here's my question.

I own a premium domain name which i use for some purpose and registered from local domain selling company. But when i check the same domain name in places like Namecheap or even in Godaddy, it says `Premium domain available for sale` with large sum of money showing [ $ 5000+ ].

Since i already own this domain, **why is it even showing for sale** as i am the domain owner with correct WHOIS records?

Comment: As Steve answered, domain brokers like GoDaddy will do this automatically in speculation if the domain meets certain criteria (e.g., it's short, contains a popular keyword, etc...). If you bought the domain within the past couple of years, the previous owner may have also listed it for sale for that amount, which gets disseminated throughout different aftermarket sites. You could try contacting these sites and requesting that they remove those listings in case you feel it detracts from its usage (a domain for sale may not impart confidence in a prospective business partner or financier...).

Comment: It looks like the previous owner seems to be the agency that puts and sell those domain name. I will look into the history and try to find like the answer as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit like me placing your house on the market without your knowledge in the hope I can make you an offer you can't refuse.

If someone tries to buy your domain, most likely a registrar will make you an offer of substantially less than $5000 and then pocket the difference if you say yes.

Be sure that if your domain has the setting, that it is locked.